# Compare different rows from database table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in my database with the name : **connected** and it look like the image below ...

[image]

What I want is to compare the rows of table in order to check that if the user with username for example niklakis has a friend with name tlagkas and if user with username for example tlagkas has a friend with name niklakis then echo a message

I tried something but it does not work.

This is the code...

```
//ALERT SYSTEM    
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT username as patient, typeValue FROM sensors WHERE status='0' AND sensorValue < min OR sensorValue > max");  
    $p1 = mysql_num_rows(queryMysql("SELECT * FROM connected
            WHERE username='$row[0]' AND friend='$username'"));
    $p2 = mysql_num_rows(queryMysql("SELECT * FROM connected
            WHERE username='$username' AND friend='$row[0]'"));  

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
    {
        if(($p1 + $p2) >1)
        {
            $alert_message= " <b><font color=red><p align='center'>User " . $row['patient'] . " Has A Health Problem with his/her ".$row['typeValue']."</font></b>";

            echo $alert_message."<br/>";
            //echo $row[0]."<br/>";
            //echo $row['patient']."<br/>";
            //echo $username."<br/>";
            //echo $p1."<br/>";
            //echo $p2."<br/>";
            //echo $p1 + $p2."<br/>";
        }  
    }
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM connected AS a 
INNER JOIN connected AS b 
ON a.username = b.friend AND a.friend = b.username
WHERE a.username='$username' AND a.friend='$row[0]'
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time . Can you explain your answer please , for example where i should place this SELECT

Comment: @DogFace, I haven't used php in about a decade, but guessing from what you originally supplied.... it should be able to replace the query used for $p1, eliminate the need for $p2, and the `($p1 + $p2) > 1` condition be changed to `$p1 > 0`.

Comment: If you mean something like that `$p1 = mysql_num_rows(queryMysql("SELECT a.* FROM connected AS a INNER JOIN connected AS b ON a.username = b.friend AND a.friend = b.username WHERE a.username='$username' AND a.friend='$row[0]'"));` and that `if($p1 > 0)` it does not work as I want

Comment: @DogFace, must be an issue in the php code then. If you are expecting the value for `$row[0]` used in the query to come from results of `$query2`, I believe it won't be set until inside the loop.